# Switching Collections and saving in Flask-Mongoengine

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am having trouble saving documents to a new collection and then deleting them from the old one. 
I create a new object like so:

```
class Test(mongo.Document):
     field = mongo.StringField()

t = Test(field="test")
t.switch_collection('default')
t.save()
t.switch_collection('switched')
t.save()
t.switch_collection('default')
t.delete()
```

It seems only to perform the first save to the default collection and then performs nothing after that. I have played around with a bunch of difference options such as reloading the object after every switch/save and from mongoengine context managers:

```
with switch_collection(Test, 'mongoswitch') as test:
    test(field="switch").save()
```

My mongo settings look like (called first):

```
 app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'db': 'TestDB'}
 mongo = MongoEngine(app)
```

Using mongoengine 0.10 and pymongo 2.8.1 with Python 3.4 .

Anyone have an idea? 
Much Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see it's old question but maybe there's someone with the same problem.. I think it's because when you have a document that has `id` set, by calling `t.save()` you only update existing document in the collection. To really save it you need to call `t.save(force_insert=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors? It had worked for me. Check records in your mongo db collections.

One possible reason from mongoengine [docs](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/connecting.html#switch-collection):

"Make sure any aliases have been registered with register_connection() or connect() before using the context manager."

Comment: No I am not getting any errors, I believe it is a problem with mongoengine 0.10, as I just downgraded to 0.09 and they save correctly. Querying that collection is a different story though..